# Why is XmlPullParser delivering two START_DOCUMENT events?

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

In an Android app I have an `XmlPullParser`:

```java
XmlResourceParser xrp = c.getResources().getXml(rid);
```

... (as you can see it's from an Android binary XML resource) ... and the first two events that it delivers are both `START_DOCUMENT`. Why? Is that normal? Intuitively, I would suppose that an XML document == one XML document, not a collection of XML documents.

My XML document *does* have more than one root-level tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
<!DOCTYPE STUFF OTHER STUFF "http://www.mydtd.com/mydtddtdtdtdtdtdtdtandroid">

<realRootTagOfMyDocument  version="9001">
    <otherStuff>
    ...
```

Does the DOCTYPE line count as another XML document?

Here is what some test code prints:

```
01-15 14:11:36.000  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document -1
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document null
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ xrp android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser@42771098
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document -1
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start document null
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ xrp android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser@42771098
01-15 14:11:36.007  11566-11566/com.mypkg I/System.out﹕ Start tag realRootTagOfMyDocument
```

... and the test code:

```java
private static void test(XmlResourceParser xrp) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    int eventType = xrp.getEventType();
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            System.out.println("Start document");
            int attributeCount = xrp.getAttributeCount();
            System.out.println("Start document " + attributeCount);
            System.out.println("Start document " + xrp.getText());
            if (attributeCount > 0)
                System.out.println("Start document " + xrp.getAttributeName(0));
            else
                System.out.println("xrp " + xrp);
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            System.out.println("Start tag " + xrp.getName());
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            System.out.println("End tag " + xrp.getName());
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            System.out.println("Text " + xrp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xrp.next();
    }
    System.out.println("End document");
    throw new Error();
}
```

Comment: Just noticed `sdk/sources/android-19/android/preference/GenericInflater.java:300` looks like it accounts for this.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`XMLPullParser` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#START_DOCUMENT):

> Signalize that parser is at the very beginning of the document and
>   nothing was read yet.

So I'd imagine that since it hasn't read anything (no start tags, end tags, end of document, etc.) it stays in the state?

Comment: One thing I failed to mention when first posting this question is that I am calling `#next()` between the two `START_DOCUMENT` events, so I don't think this is it?

Comment: Apparently you can account for the doc declaration: http://www.xmlpull.org/v1/doc/api/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getFeature%28java.lang.String%29 I would try checking if this feature is set or not.

Comment: Hmm, I bet you're on to something there.

Comment: still doesn't really explain why you're getting a second START_DOCUMENT though