# Why is the XmlResourceParser obtained from getXml() stuck on line -1?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, kotlin

I'm trying to parse an XML resource file that is on `res > xml > my_file.xml`. It seems to be stuck on line -1 and I don't quite understand why it is the case.

Here's the code:

```
class SPXMLParser(val context: Context){

    fun parse(): MutableList<Node> {
        Log.d("PONY", "We are inside SPXMLParser.parse()")
        val parser = context.resources.getXml(R.xml.my_file)
        Log.d("PONY", "Parser created text: ${parser.text} Parser line: ${parser.lineNumber}")
        return readFeed(parser)
    }

    private fun readFeed(parser: XmlPullParser): MutableList<Node> {
        Log.d("PONY", "Inside readFeed")
        val entries = mutableListOf<Node>()
        Log.d("PONY", "Before while text: ${parser.text} Parser line: ${parser.lineNumber}")
        while (parser.eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.d("PONY", "While condition met text: ${parser.text} Parser line: ${parser.lineNumber}")
            val name = parser.name
            // Starts by looking for the entry tag
            if (name == "node") {
                entries.add(readEntry(parser))
            } else {
                skip(parser)
            }
            parser.next()
        }
        Log.d("PONY", "Before returning from readFeed")
        return entries
    }
// ...
    private fun skip(parser: XmlPullParser) {
        Log.d("PONY", "Inside skip function")
        if (parser.eventType != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            Log.d("PONY", "About to throw up")
            throw IllegalStateException()
        }
        var depth = 1
        while (depth != 0) {
            Log.d("PONY", "Inception loop")
            when (parser.next()) {
                XmlPullParser.END_TAG -> depth--
                XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> depth++
            }
        }
        Log.d("PONY", "Exit skip function")
    }
}
```

And here's what we can read in the logcat:

```
06-01 15:51:01.972 12030-12030/com.example.learningtoparse D/PONY: We are inside onCreate
06-01 15:51:01.981 12030-12030/com.example.learningtoparse D/PONY: Parser has been created
    We are inside SPXMLParser.parse()
06-01 15:51:01.982 12030-12030/com.example.learningtoparse D/PONY: Parser created text: null Parser line: -1
    Inside readFeed
    Before while text: null Parser line: -1
    While condition met text: null Parser line: -1
    Else condition
    Inside skip function
    About to throw up
```

What am I missing? Why line -1?

EDIT: Posted the function `skip()` and updated the log traces. I know that the app stops because the unhandled exception `IllegalStateException` is thrown, but the question about why the parser is in line "-1" still remains.

EDIT2: [I found this question that might be related to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148929/why-is-xmlpullparser-delivering-two-start-document-events).
However, the answer seems a bit inconclusive. I also have the XML Prolog on my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

The suggestion at that answer is that the XML Prolog is read but we're still in the event `START_DOCUMENT`, since the root tag hasn't been read yet.

Comment: @tynn Definitely. Further traces reveal this is a problem with `skip()`, but I suspect I'm not using `getXml()` correctly.

Comment: Could you add the `skip()` method to your code here?

Comment: @tynn Yes. I've edited the question with the code of the method and some traces that reveal the exact point where the program stops executing.