# XmlResourceParser stays at the START_DOCUMENT state after calling next()

Tags: android, android-xml, android-xmlpullparser

The following code throws an exception at the 4th line

```
XmlResourceParser parser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.file);
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT, null, null);
parser.next();
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, null);
```

and after adding debug print statements it turns out that the parser is still in the *START_DOCUMENT* state after the first call to `next()`. Adding another call to `next()` fixes the issue. Such behaviour is wrong per the official Android reference as it [says](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#START_DOCUMENT):

> **START_DOCUMENT**
>
> Signalize that parser is at the very beginning of the document and
>   nothing was read yet. This event type can only be observed by calling
>   getEvent() before the first call to next(), nextToken, or nextTag()).

Comment: `Log.d` the values of `getEventType()` and `getName()` before and after `next()` method, what do you see?

Comment: `0` in both cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is XmlPullParser delivering two START\_DOCUMENT events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148929/why-is-xmlpullparser-delivering-two-start-document-events)